# Why is QGIS project in recent projects greyed out?

Tags: qgis, qgs

When I open QGIS, there are projects which cannot be chosen. They work when I start browser of files and click in directory where the projects are.

Are there options to change it?

[image: Print screen of my fist screen of Qgis. Almost of them are unable to choose.]

Comment: Normally means the path can't be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest solution is to just load your project from your new path. But if you really want to change the paths which are stored in QGIS, from the menubar go to:

```
Settings > Options > Advanced > UI > recentProjects
```

These are stored in numbered folders, locate the one you're interested in and you will see several files:

[image: Recent projects]

You can then change the value of the path (and title) either:

- Manually by clicking the value and entering the correct path
- Automatically from the **Python Console** using:

  ```
  from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
  QSettings().setValue('UI/recentProjects/1/path', 'path/to/project')
  QSettings().setValue('UI/recentProjects/1/title', 'path/to/project')
  ```